# Pointing Sub-Domain on Windows Apache Server to NancyFX Self-Host

Tags: nancy, port80, zpanel

Firstly, I'd just like to say that I don't know which StackExchange site this should go on, please could you let me know where I should put it.

I have an Apache server managed by the windows version of zPanel. I have a windows service which runs a NancyFX Self-Host server.

Currently they are on two different ports, zPanel sits on port 80 and Nancy sits on port 3579. I was wondering if there was a way that I could setup a sub-domain from one of my domains to point to the Nancy server so that they could both sit on port 80?

Failing a sub-domain, a folder `http://example.com/nancy` will also be acceptable.

Thanks for any help